# asyncio not stopping where expected

Tags: python, python-asyncio

With this asyncio code, my tutor says that all coroutines (here the 50 "fetch_page") first stop at the first `async with` and wait, then all of them resume from there and stop at the second `async with`, then finally all of them all return.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch_page(url):
    print(1)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
       print(2)
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            print(3)
            return response.status

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    
tasks = [fetch_page('http://google.com') for i in range(50)]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

I'm debugging this, and I must say he's wrong. While debugging, I see all coroutines going sequentially to the second `async with`, where they all stop. Then once all the 50 coroutines resumes, they do the `session.get(url)` and return.

But why not all of the couroutines stop at the first `async with` ?

Print output : "1 2 1 2 1 2 ... 3 3 3 ...", instead of "1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 ... 3 3 3 ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little piece of info is missing here:

asyncio is a single-threaded library based on event loop.

What happens in this case is that `aiohttp.ClientSession() as session` is not an I/O expensive operation, it doesn't take time to execute, that's why it gets executed immediately even before the iterator gets to the next loop cycle.

Why `3333` get's printed last? because you're making an I/O that takes time, more than looping for 50 times.

For more details read here: [asyncio python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: Great !  Am I right in saying this :  each coroutine do their job, without stopping, but the async/await is permitting the suspending/resuming of execution so that other coroutine can enter doing their job.  This is not multithreading, it's all on the main thread.

Comment: @trogne all threads are suspect to suspending/resuming when they require more than certain period of time determined by operating system task scheduler. so yes async/await will make the "asynchronous" section of your code suspect to being suspended.

Comment: Coroutines do not "delegate to other thread", asyncio is single-threaded.

Answer (score 2):

> But why not all of the couroutines stop at the first `async with`?

Just like any other `await`, an `async with` doesn't guarantee that the coroutine will suspend there, but it *allows* the coroutine to suspend if there is reason to do so. In this case, merely creating a `ClientSession` is an operation that can be done without suspending any coroutine, so each of them simply proceeds further.

Entering the second `async with` must obtain a response object, which requires that the request has been sent and the HTTP headers received. Executed on a non-blocking socket, some of these operations will signal that the data is not immediately available (because it needs to reach the server, and the server has to craft a response, and then the response has to travel back to us), and asyncio handles that by suspending the coroutine. This is why the second `async with` is practically guaranteed to suspend each coroutine that reaches it.